# How to rename folders dynamically using multiple appender in log4net?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, log4net, log4net-appender

How to configure log4net which it has two appenders in App.config.
the first appender works and i succeeded to find out how to send parameter to ***%property{LogFolderName}*** but when i tried to configure the second appender it doesn't work, it create the folder with this name %property{MEFolder}. The main purpose is how to point to the second appender and set dynamically the second property ***%property{MEFolder}*** (programmatically) like the first one:
here is my App.config

```
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\AOI3DV2\LogTransformerFile\%property{LogFolderName}\logL08_%date{yyyyMMdd}.txt"/>
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="500MB"/>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
    <levelMin value="INFO" />
    <levelMax value="INFO" />
  </filter>
  <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="LogWarningFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <file value="D:\AOI3DV2\LogsME\%property{MEFolder}\logMEConnectWS_" />
  <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'-info.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <bufferSize value="100" />
  <maximumFileSize value="500MB" />
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
    <levelMin value="ERROR" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="Header" value="" />
    <param name="Footer" value="" />
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

this is te form.cs:

```
  // It work
 string LogFolderName = GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name;
   if (!Directory.Exists(LogFolderName))
      {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(LogFolderName);
                
       }
   log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogFolderName"]=LogFolderName;
   
   //It doesn't work 
   string MEFolder= GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name;
   if (!Directory.Exists(LogFolderName))
      {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(MEFolder);
                
       }
   log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["MEFolder"]=MEFolder;
```

Comment: Add the `type="log4net.Util.PatternString"` specifier to the `file` tag of the 2nd appender, _which is present for the first appender_.